# Android Pull To Refresh ListView: eliminate arrow hint

Tags: android, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

I am using [this library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) from Chris Banes (I will never thank this man enough). It has two different behaviors depending on the android version. I want to get rid of the graphical hint on the PullToRefresListView (circled in the image below) that is shown only on devices with android lower than 4.0.

Does anybody knows how to do it?

[image]

SOLUTION:

for anybody in the future searching for the same solution here it is: in the PullToRefreshAdapterViewBase class change getShowIndicatorInternal method from this:

```
private boolean getShowIndicatorInternal() {

    return mShowIndicator && isPullToRefreshEnabled();
}
```

to this:

```
private boolean getShowIndicatorInternal() {

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use a layout XML file, you can also specify `ptr:ptrShowIndicator="false"` inside the `PullToRefreshView`'s declaration. For example:

```
    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
        xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/pullToRefreshListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ptr:ptrShowIndicator="false" >
    </com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView>
```

For other attributes, you can refer to [/res/values/attrs.xml](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/res/values/attrs.xml) in the library, which is self-documented.

You may also find the [sample project](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/tree/master/sample) worth looking at.

Comment: That's the best! Could you tell me where in the code I can see these attributes? Where can I look to know which attributes I can give to a custom element like com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView ? Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome~ :) Please see my edited answer for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty- Simply replace the image file for arrow hint with a transparent image in res folder of library.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say try to see if you can adjust the code to simply take it out. 
I don't know if there are any methods added to do this for you, but if there are they should be easy to find.

Scrolling through the code a bit quickly, this might be something;

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/internal/IndicatorLayout.java

Although i'm not sure if this is actually that arrow, since it doesn't show any hints in this class about being version-based.

Comment: Thank you! That was it! Starting from there I had to go through a little bit of other classes to find where it decides if that indicator should be shown or not and set to always return false.

Comment: Good :) You could separate that into a nice method instead and have it as a setting. Perhaps Chris Banes can accept it as a change and others can enjoy it too ;)

Comment: Does anyone knows how to show the indicator even if the empty text view is showed when the list is empty?